# In a react class component what is the purpose of using curried function with no arguments?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, currying

Saw this setup in material ui react components demo and was wondering what the purpose of this curried function is:

```
toggleDrawer = (side, open) => () => {
   this.setState({
      [side]: open,
   });
};
```

elsewhere they call it like so:

```
<Button onClick={this.toggleDrawer('left', true)}>Open Left</Button>
```

Comment: The curry is so the function isn't invoked immediately, the inner function's reference is passed to `onClick` so that it is invoked with the scoped parameters of the outer function.

Comment: In other words, the outer function is invoked when the component is rendered; the inner function is invoked when the button is clicked.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts is this to avoid using arrow functions in render for performance issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

toggleDrawer is a factory that can produce other functions. It's being used to reduce code duplication.  If this is the only spot in the code where there's an onClick then it's not very useful, but presumably there are other lines of code like this:

```
<Button onClick={this.toggleDrawer('top', true)}>Foo</Button>
<Button onClick={this.toggleDrawer('bottom', true)}>Bar</Button>
<Button onClick={this.toggleDrawer('left', false)}>Baz</Button>
<Button onClick={this.toggleDrawer('cobb', 'salad')}>Yum</Button>
```

Personally i'd have named it something different to make it clear it's a factory, something like `makeToggleHandler`

Comment: Yes there are other lines of code but I'm not sure why they use a curried function and not just an arrow function. Like why not just `toggleDrawer = (side, open) => {...}` what's the point of the second empty arrow function?

Comment: That's the function that gets produced. toggleDrawer is a factory, the second function is the click handler. Your proposal certainly would work, but then you'd have to create the extra function yourself in the JSX, as in `<Button onClick={() => this.toggleDrawer('left', true)}/>` Either way, an extra function is needed, it's just a matter of where you want to create it.

Answer (score 0):

Curring is partial invocation of a function. It's like if you have given one or two spice to the curry and cooked little bit, still you can add further spice to it. A simple example will look like-

```
  return function(num){
    return base + num;
  }
}

var addTen = addBase(10);
addTen(5); //15
addTen(80); //90
addTen(-5); //5
```

Explanation: You are creating a closure that returns a function. When you are curring with a new number, new number is added to the base you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is that in order to avoid the onClick being invoked immediately on render you can call it like so:

```
<Button onClick={() => this.toggleDrawer('left', true)}>Open Left</Button>
```

However, using an arrow function like this inside the render has performance implications in larger apps so this alternate method is taking the arrow function out of the render. So now you can simply do:

```
<Button onClick={this.toggleDrawer('left', true)}>Open Left</Button>
```

@PatrickRoberts gave me the right answer as a comment and I'm willing to give him the points if he posts the answer here.

Comment: There's no performance difference between the two. In your first example, you're creating an arrow function inline and passing it to onClick. In the second, you're calling a function, and that function creates an arrow function, and then you pass it to onClick. Either way, a new arrow function is created on every render.